# Android: Data from Broadcast from AsyncTask not getting data through

Tags: android

I am using an Intent to Broadcast data from a AsyncTask thread back to a the main Activity.  The Broadcast is received my the Activity with no problem, but I am not seeing the Uri data or CharSequence data.  They are both null.

On Service side in AsyncTask:

```
   public static final String LOCATION_UPDATE = "com.locationTest.lct.LOCATION_UPDATE";
   char[] buffer = new char[10];
   buffer[0] = 't';
   buffer[1] = 'e';
   buffer[2] = 's';
   buffer[3] = 't';

   Intent intent = new Intent(LOCATION_UPDATE);
   intent.putExtra("location",buffer);
   sendBroadcast(intent);
```

On activity side in main Activity class:

```
public static final String LOCATION_UPDATE = "com.locationTest.lct.LOCATION_UPDATE";
   public class LocationBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
       public void onReceive(Context context,Intent intent)
       {
        Uri data = intent.getData();
        CharSequence location = intent.getCharSequenceExtra("location");
    }
}
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    iService = startService(new Intent(this,InputService2.class));
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(LOCATION_UPDATE);
    LocationBroadcastReceiver r = new LocationBroadcastReceiver();
    registerReceiver(r,filter);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be because you're creating a char array and then trying to get it as a char sequence. Try with

```
String location = new String(intent.getCharArrayExtra("location"));
```

or something similar so that you're using the correct get method from the Intent.

Comment: No I replaced the above with char[] location = intent.getCharArrayExtra("location"); and I still get null.  In addition, the URI is null also so it is something in the setup that is causing the problem.

Comment: I found it.  I was starting the service before initializing the Broadcast Receiver.  Then the service would send the first message (upon starting) before the receiver was fully initialize.  The answer is to initialize the receiver first and then the service.  Basically it was a race condition between the asyc task and the main thread.

Comment: Ah, I should have spotted that. I should mention, the common practice is to register the receiver in onResume and unregister is in onPause.